# An Interesting phenomenon observed in a 10 by 6 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, periodic-functions

As shown in the table below, given the matrix M=(x,y), where x=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10; y = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12.When the value of x is even (odd), the value of y can only be even (odd). Arrange x and y from left to right respectively. After x reaches 10, return to the initial value, that is, the number 1, and continue to arrange. When y gets to 12, it goes back to its original value, which is the number 1, and continues. Finish the first row, then the second row, and so on, all six rows. After the whole process, get the following table. Look at the vertical direction, the y coordinates are always appeared in a reverse order. For example, in the first column (highlight in yellow), the value of y in the first row is 1, then the value of y in the second row goes back to 11, and the next row goes back to 9... . Why does this happen?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Because $y+10\equiv y-2\pmod{12}$.